# programming an universal remote control

Tags: c#, windows, controls, hid

I have a remote control RM200 and I want to program it
so I can detect key presses and send them to applications.

Now, which API can I use in Windows?

HID usb API? IRDA API?

I'm confused.

My remote is an IRDA remote but sometime I read that I can program this device
with HID USB API????

Comment: Good luck with this project, I've upvoted and tagged it because I think a lot of hobbyists could use this information.  Personally, I'd go with HID because then you don't have to write a custom USB driver -- HID is pretty well documented.  IRDA has the obvious advantage of not needing the cable, but then again, how many desktops have IRDA?  Only my laptops have had it available.  Perhaps they have an IRDA dongle but then that's extra hardware you have to buy.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you cannot use the IRDA interface to receive infrared remote control sinals, because IRDA is a special protocol and the interface cannot be "abused" to receive other signals.

To receive your remote control's infrared signals you will need an extra device. Infrared receivers for your serial port are quite easy to build.

A good source for information and software is: http://www.lirc.org/

The windows port of lirc is called WinLIRC an can be found here: http://winlirc.sourceforge.net/overview.html

Comment: I have a VFD display (it cames with an infrared sensor) from Soundgraph (in an Antec case) and I connected it with an usb cable. So for me the extra device you say is that and so I can program it with HID API?